# India - Claim missed LIC premium in declaration

Tags: income-tax, india, life-insurance, premiums, electronic-filing

I had to submit LIC premium paid receipts with my employer by December. One of the premium I could pay only on February and this was not considered for the last financial years' tax deduction calculation. Now I got to file returns and would like to do it myself in the income tax website. How to claim returns for the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are filling in ITR-1 using Income Tax department website, fill in the details in B4 under section 80C.

As this would not match with TRACES Form-16 issued by Employer, there maybe a query at which point in time you would need to furnish the details.

In future it is advisable to pay the premium early and submit to your Employer.

Comment: With LIC I'm allowed to pay only before 30 days. So for the month of Feb I couldn't pay by Dec.

Comment: If I add the extra amount in 80C, no proof is asked for and the calculated amount is shown in refundable. No provision for uploading proof. Shall I file the returns without proof.

Comment: @itsraja Yes that is right. There is no proof requested. However when IT Returns get processed, at times there can be a query from IT department. You have to keep the proof hand and submit it then.

Comment: This is what I've always done. I have always got a refund quite promptly , without any query from the IT dept.